# GroupBy with multiple Join, Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I want to `groupBy` `teacher_id` and by `day_of_the_week`, with this current code I don't get any error, but I get no join at the end. If I use only `teacher_id` and `day_of_the_week` in `groupBy` I get errors.

```
    $schedule = Schedule::select(
                'schedules.teacher_id',
                'schedules.day_of_the_week',
                'schedules.semester',
                'schedules.hour_start',
                'schedules.hour_end',
                'teachers.name as teacher_name',
                'rooms.name as room_name',
                'groups.name as group_name',
                'courses.name as course_name',
                )
            ->leftJoin('teachers','teachers.id','schedules.teacher_id')
            ->leftJoin('rooms','rooms.id','schedules.room_id')
            ->leftJoin('groups','groups.id','schedules.group_id')
            ->leftJoin('courses','courses.id','schedules.course_id')
            ->groupBy(['schedules.teacher_id',
            'schedules.day_of_the_week',
            'schedules.semester',
            'schedules.hour_start',
            'schedules.hour_end',
            'teacher_name',
            'room_name',
            'group_name',
            'course_name'])
            ->get();


//Second version
Schedule::select('schedules.*')
    ->with(['teachers' => function($query){
              return $query->groupBy('name');
          },'groups', 'courses','rooms'])   
    ->get();
```

**The current response.**

[image]

**Update**

I find a way to do this with the first code from above and but on a deeper level on `day_of_the_week`, I am not sure how..

```
$schedule = $schedule->groupBy('teacher_name');  // on collection
```

Comment: The reason you get error is "probably"; including only 2 in group by but selecting more than 2(excluding aggregated ones). It will be easier if you provide table structure, sample data, and expected results.

Comment: I uploaded a image with my current response. The structure is pretty simple, all teacher_id .. example_id. are FK . Now I try a new version where I am using with([...]), and I write all relationships belonsTo.

Comment: Did you get and error like this `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column....` ?

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'one column will be here...' isn't in GROUP BY.

Comment: That's the postgresql version of the error i shared(mine was mysql). As i said in the first message - you are including non-aggregated columns in select statement which are not in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that I tried and it works. GroupBy on different table fields you can do only by Change DB mode strict to false. Goto
**ProjectRootDir/Config/database.php** file goto Mysql and change the **strict** value to ***FALSE*** the default value is ***TRUE***.

Hope your problem will solve.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, but I am using PostgreSQL.